# AXIS: sending image RGB 24bit on AXI

Tags: image-processing, vivado, vivado-hls

I am doing a project on my university where I have to make some algorithm which needs at least two frames of video, but I cannot use any camera - I can only storage somewhere my images.
I want to do some image processing in vivado HLS on one pixel which has 24 bits (8 bits for red, 8 for green and 8 for blue), I knew how to make input stream for 24 bits, but I don't know how can I send 24 bits when axi supports 8,16 and 32 bits.
1. What is the best way to storage my images? DMA? 
2. If I use DMA, my output is 32 bits - how can I get 24 bits, to send it on my module?
3. Is it a good solution to make input for 24 bits? I can see in that project https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1167.pdf that sb have input stream which is a whole image? and later only using some OpenCv algorithms and get the result!
Is it possible without HDMI?

I will be grateful for any help.